# SQL Server pivot vs. multiple join

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, join, pivot

What is more efficient to use in SQL Server 2005: PIVOT or MULTIPLE JOIN?

For example, I got this query using two joins:

```
SELECT p.name, pc1.code as code1, pc2.code as code2
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN product_code pc1
    ON p.product_id=pc1.product_id AND pc1.type=1
    INNER JOIN product_code pc2
    ON p.product_id=pc2.product_id AND pc2.type=2
```

I can do the same using PIVOT:

```
SELECT name, [1] as code1, [2] as code2
FROM (
    SELECT p.name, pc.type, pc.code
    FROM product p
        INNER JOIN product_code pc
        ON p.product_id=pc.product_id
    WHERE pc.type IN (1,2)) prods1
PIVOT(
    MAX(code) FOR type IN ([1], [2])) prods2
```

Which one will be more efficient?

Comment: Your `PIVOT` version can return incorrect results if 2 products have the same name. You need to add `p.product_id` to the `select` list of the derived table.

Comment: You're right. This was just a quick example.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The answer will of course be "it depends" but based on testing this end...

Assuming

1. 1 million products
2. `product` has a clustered index on `product_id`
3. Most (if not all) products have corresponding information in the `product_code` table
4. Ideal indexes present on `product_code` for both queries.

The `PIVOT` version ideally needs an index `product_code(product_id, type) INCLUDE (code)` whereas the `JOIN` version ideally needs an index `product_code(type,product_id) INCLUDE (code)`

If these are in place giving the plans below

[image: Plans]

then the `JOIN` version is more efficient.

In the case that `type 1` and `type 2` are the only `types` in the table then the `PIVOT` version slightly has the edge in terms of number of reads as it doesn't have to seek into `product_code` twice but that is more than outweighed by the additional overhead of the stream aggregate operator

#### PIVOT

```
Table 'product_code'. Scan count 1, logical reads 10467
Table 'product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4750
   CPU time = 3297 ms,  elapsed time = 3260 ms.
```

#### JOIN

```
Table 'product_code'. Scan count 2, logical reads 10471
Table 'product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4750
   CPU time = 1906 ms,  elapsed time = 1866 ms.
```

If there are additional `type` records other than `1` and `2` the `JOIN` version will increase its advantage as it just does merge joins on the relevant sections of the `type,product_id` index whereas the `PIVOT` plan uses `product_id, type` and so would have to scan over the additional `type` rows that are intermingled with the `1` and `2` rows.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely consider this the next time I think about using PIVOT instead of JOIN. By the way, being more specific, I have a non clustered index product_code(product_id), and the table product has about half million records, while the table product_code has about one million, with 4 different types.

Comment: @guillegr123 - running `SET STATISTICS IO ON;SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` then running them both and looking at the output of those along with the actual execution plans is probably the best way to see for your specific indexes and data. I usually assign the results to variables so that takes the time it sends to send back the results out of the equation. i.e. `declare @name varchar(10), @code1 varchar(10), @code2 varchar(10);SELECT @name = name, @code1 = [1],@code2 = [2] FROM ...`

Comment: @MartinSmith Do you know if there's a term for this design pattern (i.e. where you have a table providing "user-defined columns")?  It feels like there should be one... https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369639/correct-terminology-for-a-table-which-provides-dynamic-columns?noredirect=1#comment809875_369639

Answer (score 6):

I don't think anyone can tell you which will be more efficient without knowledge of your indexing and table size.

That said, rather than hypothesizing about which is more efficient you should analyze the execution plan of these two queries.