# Table design in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

Could you please make some comments on the following strange and complicated design. I want to continue with this design. It is an existing design and not created by me.

**Employee**

```
EmpID
-----
  1
  2
```

**Attribute**

```
AttributeID Name Visible
------------------------
  1        Name    1
  2        Age     1
  3        Salary  1
```

**EmployeeAttribute**

```
EmpID AttributeID Value
-----------------------
 1       1        Rauf
 1       2        23
 1       3        100000 
 2       1        Amal
 2       3        50000
```

I want to select the above table as follows

```
EmpID   Name  Age  Salary 
-------------------------
  1     Rauf   23   100000 
  2     Amal         50000
```

How can I do it in SQL Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model). To get the desired results you would need to `PIVOT` on `AttributeID` either using `PIVOT` or as below.

```
SELECT EmpID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeID =1 THEN Value END) AS Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeID =2 THEN Value END) AS Age,
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeID =3 THEN Value END) AS Salary
FROM EmployeeAttribute
GROUP BY EmpID
```

EAV is flexible but has a lot of disadvantages (google "EAV anti pattern" to find out more on this.)

Comment: Could you please use query with table names. See my EDIT.

Comment: @Rauf - Just replace `T` with `EmployeeAttribute`. You don't need the other tables for your desired results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM EmployeeAttributes
PIVOT (
     MAX(VALUE)
     FOR AttributeID IN (1,2,3)
      )
      ORDER EmployeeID` gives error . Error **Incorrect syntax near '1'.**Why ?

Comment: @Rauf - You would need `SELECT * FROM EmployeeAttributes PIVOT ( MAX(VALUE) FOR AttributeID IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) P ORDER BY EmployeeID`

Comment: Well It works. But I can not use like this `SELECT * FROM EmployeeAttributes
PIVOT (
     MAX(VALUE)
     FOR AttributeID IN (SELECT  [AttributeID] FROM [Attributes])
      ) P`. Why :( ?

Comment: @Rauf - That simply isn't supported. If you need a dynamic pivot you would need dynamic SQL (googling "dynamic pivot" should bring back some example code)

Comment: http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122862/change-column-name-while-using-pivot-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

You can self join too

```
SELECT
   T1.EmpID,
   T1.Value As [name], T2.Value As [age], T3.Value As [salary]
FROM
   EmployeeAttribute T1
   JOIN
   EmployeeAttribute T2 ON T1.EmpID= T2.EmpID
   JOIN
   EmployeeAttribute T3 ON T1.EmpID= T3.EmpID
WHERE
   T1.AttributeID =1
   AND
   T2.AttributeID =2
   AND
   T3.AttributeID =3
```

Comment: There are 3 attributes, so I need to use 3 joins . Right ?

Comment: @Rauf - Depending on your indexes [multiple joins can be more efficient than PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448453/sql-server-pivot-vs-multiple-join/7449213#7449213)

Comment: @Rauf: 3 attributes = 3 tables = 2 JOINs

Comment: @gbn  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122862/change-column-name-while-using-pivot-sql-server-2008

Comment: @gbn I used PIVOT here. But self join is also nice :) .