# How to select item matching Only IN List in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can one select only the items he want in the IN list? for example

```
select * from pagetags where TagID in (1,2,4)
```

Now I want all the pages which has all the above 3 IDs assigned to them (1,2,4), not just any of them but all of them?

Is there a way? any other operator? I have already tried `= Any` and `= All` but no luck.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The term for this type of problem is [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). One way below.

```
SELECT PageID
FROM   pagetags
WHERE  TagID IN ( 1, 2, 4 )
GROUP  BY PageID
HAVING Count(DISTINCT TagID) = 3
```

Comment: ok, i should have write my original schema because that is more difficult than the example above :) but you saved me there, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
SELECT id, Tag FROM (
SELECT id, Tag, COUNT(*) OVER(partition by id) as cnt
FROM pagetags
WHERE Tag in(1,2,4)
GROUP BY id, tag
) a WHERE a.cnt = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer from Martin Smith

```
SELECT PageID
FROM   pagetags
WHERE  TagID IN ( 1, 2, 4 )
GROUP  BY PageID
HAVING Count(DISTINCT TagID) = 3
```

is correct but if speed is a problem then try these.

I have a large table doing the same thing and got 10x better performance with the following.
0.2 seconds versus 2.0 seconds for query returning  272 from a table with 3 million rows.
Also tested on a bigger table with 5 tags and same 10x but now 0.5 versus 5.0.
Index is PageID, TagID with millions of PageID and hundreds of TagID.
Common scenario where many objects are tagged multivalue property.

```
    SELECT distinct(p1.PageID)
    FROM   pagetags p1
    JOIN   pagetags p2
      ON   p2.PageID = p1.PageID
      AND  p2.TagID = 2 
    JOIN   pagetags p3
      ON   p3.PageID = p1.PageID
      AND  p3.TagID = 4
    WHERE  p1.PageID = 1
 ORDER BY  p1.PageID
```

or

```
   SELECT  distinct(PageID)
    FROM   pagetags
    WHERE  TagID = 1
   INTERSECT
   SELECT  distinct(PageID)
    FROM   pagetags
    WHERE  TagID = 2 
   INTERSECT
   SELECT  distinct(PageID)
    FROM   pagetags
    WHERE  TagID = 4 
 ORDER BY  PageID
```

Prefer the last as with over 5 joins the query optimizer often will make some bad decisions.
And with this have not used up the Group By if you need it for another aggregation.

Comment: It depends on the indexes available and the number of tags in the system. Basically the same as comparing [`PIVOT` vs `JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448453/sql-server-pivot-vs-multiple-join/7449213#7449213). If the number of tags to look at is variable this is not very extendable except if the query is generated via dynamic SQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith In my case the index is PageID TagID.  Less than 1000 TagID but can have millions of PageID.  Used by a program. So I gladly take the 10x performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct(PageID)
FROM   pagetags
WHERE  TagID IN (1,2,4)
and PageID in
(select distinct(PageID) from pagetags group by PageID having count(TagID)=3)
group by PageID
```

Comment: Some explanation might help!