# Adding list elements to WHERE clause

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to add another condition to this `WHERE` clause:

`stmt = 'SELECT account_id FROM asmithe.data_hash WHERE percent < {};'.format(threshold)`

I have the variable `juris` which is a list. The value of `account_id` and `juris` are related in that when an `account_id` is created, it contains the substring of a `juris`.

I want to add to the query the condition that it needs to match anyone of the `juris` elements. Normally I would just add `...AND account_id LIKE '{}%'".format(juris)` but this doesn't work because `juris` is a list.

How do I add all elements of a list to the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex` with operator `~`:

```
 juris = ['2','7','8','3']

'select * from tbl where id ~ \'^({})\''.format('|'.join(juris))
```

which leads to this query:

```
select * from tbl where id ~ '^(2|7|8|3)'
```

This brings the rows which their `id` **start with** any of 2,7,8 or 3. Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d1f39/1) for it.

If you want the `id` start with `2783` use:

```
select * from tbl where id ~ '^2783'
```

and if `id` **contains** any of 2,7,8 or 3

```
select * from t where id ~ '.*(2|7|8|3).*'
```

Comment: How do you combine this with a regular expression?

Comment: No but it would be any row where id *started* with 2,7,8 or 3. That's what I mean by using LIKE and regular expressions.

Comment: No, you want records that their `account_id` is in `juris` , right?

Comment: Not like that. I mean the string account_id contains the string juris. So if it does return the row. So account_id is always composed of taking the juris and appending more characters to it.

Comment: Ah, I got it now, I changed the answer.

Comment: I think your space in `'| '` breaks it

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping juris is a list of strings? If so, this might help:

```
myquery = ("SELECT accountid FROM asmithe.data_hash "
           "WHERE percent in (%s)" % ",".join(map(str,juris)))
```

See these links:

1. [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)
2. [How to select item matching Only IN List in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563952/how-to-select-item-matching-only-in-list-in-sql-server)
3. [String formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: Ahem, SQL injection? Please never, ever provide example code like this, it's horrible insecure.

Answer (score 0):

[Stop using string formatting with SQL. Right now](http://bobby-tables.com/). Understand?

OK now. There's a construct, `ANY` in SQL, that lets you take an operator and apply it to an array.  `psycopg2` supports passing a Python list as an SQL `ARRAY[]`. So in this case you can just

```
curs.execute('SELECT account_id FROM asmithe.data_hash WHERE percent LIKE ANY (%s)', (thelist,))
```

Note here that `%s` is the psycopg2 query-parameter placeholder. It's not actually a format specifier. The second argument is a tuple, the query parameters. The first (and only) parameter is the list.

There's also `ALL`, which works like `ANY` but is true only if all the matches are true, not just if one or more is true.