# SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same column from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pick values from the same column using an `and` clause query, that looks something like this:

```
select * 
from degree_detail_result 
where course_id=1 and course_id=2 and course_id=3
```

What is wrong with the above query?

Comment: Give example data and desired results. Those anded conditions are mutually exclusive for any row.

Comment: Please *spell out* your condition.  My best guess is that you need `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: Think about it: how can the same column contain the value 1 2 and 3 **at the same time**?

Answer (score 3):

Use `in`:

```
select * from degree_detail_result where course_id in (1,2,3)
```

Note that `and` will not work as it requires the conditions on either side of it to be true at the same time, which obviously is not possible.

If you want to get the results *next* to each other instead of in separate rows, you can use `pivot`:

```
select * from degree_detail_result
pivot (min(degree_id) for course_id in ([1], [2], [3])) as degree
```

If you want to get a *parent* ID (not mentioned in your question), for which there are records for *course_id* 1, 2 and 3, you can do this:

```
select   degree_id from degree_detail_result
where    course_id in (1,2,3)
group by degree_id
having   count(distinct course_id) = 3
```

Comment: ok supose i want to know what is degree id where the course is 1 and 2 and 3. tell me what i have to do ?? the above method tried it also fatch the degree id which have use the same comon id.

Comment: Just select it? What you write can be interpreted in many ways. Please edit your question, provide sample data, and the output you expect to get from that data.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12563952/73226 based on that comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from degree_detail_result 
where course_id=1 and course_id=2 and course_id=3
```

This query will not work, because this condition cannot be met at the same time.

You can try using the `INTERSECT`, but you need to specify the particular columns you are looking for instead of `SELECT *`

i.e. the following will return no rows

```
SELECT *
FROM   degree_detail_result
WHERE  course_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM   degree_detail_result
WHERE  course_id = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM   degree_detail_result
WHERE  course_id = 3;
```

and you would need

```
SELECT degree_id
FROM   degree_detail_result
WHERE  course_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT degree_id
FROM   degree_detail_result
WHERE  course_id = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT degree_id
FROM   degree_detail_result
WHERE  course_id = 3;
```

Comment: This is redundant. What not use IN or just the Boolean OR versus hitting the table 3 times?

Comment: Thanks for the responce