# Lowering CPU cost on an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a query like below where table150k has 150k records and table3m has 3m records. On our production servers, we have to run this query for a single record at a time very frequently. This costs a lot of cpu power.

```
select t.id, t1.field1 as f1, t2.field1 as f2, t3.field1 as f3, ..., t12.field1 as f12
from table150k t
inner join table3m t1 on t1.fk = t.id and t1.[type] = 1
inner join table3m t2 on t2.fk = t.id and t2.[type] = 2
inner join table3m t3 on t3.fk = t.id and t3.[type] = 3
...
inner join table3m t12 on t12.fk = t.id and t12.[type] = 12
where t.id = @id
```

When I remove inner joins from this query, it works fine. When they are included, our servers suffer cpu.

How should I optimize this query, data structure or scenario so that frequent fetches of data do not cost cpu as high?

Comment: When you remove the joins you are only selecting from a single table. Adding the joins increases the complexity so yes the CPU will increase.

Comment: Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this". Doctor: "Then stop doing that"...

Comment: why do you need to join the same table multiple times?

Comment: What indexes are on the tables involved and what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: why do you want to join the table3m multiple times? I mean how about inner joining table3m with in clause for type from 1 to 12 and then consolidating the records at the application level.

Comment: Are these 1-1 joins?  How many duplicates are there for t.id?  And, are you really selecting different fields from the tables, or is it:  `t1.field as field1, t2.field as field2, . . .`?

Comment: @Martin Smith and Ankit I am afraid that that will pull 12 times more data, which will create another huge problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff These are 1-1 joins. There is exactly one record for a given user and type in table3m. I am always selecting the same field on table3m.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien There is only one table3m. The data always come from that table.

Comment: @SerhatÖzgel - No idea why you `@`-ed me in that comment. I asked you a question not gave you any suggestion.

Comment: Please try [SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx) and show us the results.

Comment: XML actual execution plan please. Not text.

Comment: @mbeckish I will do that but the actual query is a lot more complicated than this. I hope it will not be too much confusing.

Comment: What fields from table150k besides id is necessary for you?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko A few, but lots of fields from some other joined tables are necessary. I did not include them in the sample to keep things simple.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an index on `table3m(fk)`?

That should fix your problem.

An alternative formulation is:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when m.[type] = 1 then field end) as field1,
       max(case when m.[type] = 2 then field end) as field2,
       . . .
       max(case when m.[type] = 12 then field end) as field12
from table150k t join
     table3m m
     on m.fk = t.id and m.[type] in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
where t.id = @id
group by t.id
```

This structure has all the data coming from the same column in the "3m" table.

Comment: How about on `table3m(fk + [type])`?

Comment: @JoeEnos We have that too :(

Comment: I will give alternative formulation a try and post results.

Comment: Gordon's answer is right.  SQL Server will process his query making a single pass over the table.  You could also use the PIVOT operator.  Regarding the index, table150k should be clustered on id. The table3m needs an index with fk and type, probably in that order but perhaps reversed.  If only a small portion of table3m meet the criteria and it's not updated frequently, consider a materialized view of just those two columns.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden - A single pass over the table isn't necessarily going to be better than multiple joins with correct indexes. [See plans and timings here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448453/sql-server-pivot-vs-multiple-join/7449213#7449213)

Comment: @Martin, your test results are interesting, and don't speak well of the efficiency of PIVOT which by rights should be faster than a bunch of CASE ... MAX clauses (since the server has more information about the intent).  As usual, "it depends".

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the two tables does not change frequently I follow an alternate method to create a caching table(just another table) which just holds the result of the above query.

Comment: business logic needs that data to be instant :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from table150k t
inner join table3m t1 on t1.fk = t.id and t1.[type] in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
where t.id = @id
```

Comment: Will not this produce 12 times more records?

Comment: its an inner join, not left join

Comment: It still will fetch 12 times more records because each row will be duplicated for each record in table3m.

Comment: On this example it looks simple but on actual production code, there are a lot of columns other than t1.Id and table3m.field1. All those will be replicated 12 times.

Comment: @SerhatÖzgel - That's true, but it still might perform better.  If you try it out and this does perform better, it might be worth changing your app to expect one record per detail value, rather than one column per detail.

Comment: @mbeckish Fair enough. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id, t1.type, t1.field1
from table150k as t
inner join table3m as t1 on t1.fk = t.id 
where t.id = @id and t1.[type] in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

This will bring back 12 records(assuming they all exist).

The advantage here is speed on the server side, disadvantage is you will have to map each record to a corresponding column in a datatable or value on an object based on the type value once you get it into your application.

Comment: the problem is that this code melts all the different [type] into a single column, whereas the OP wants them separated in different columns

Comment: Yes this will get one value record per type. thats why I qualified it by saying he'll have to reorganize the data once he gets it into his application. Its a bit more work in the data access layer but its a hell of a lot quicker than 12 inner joins on the same table.